# JavaScript Else If Statements

Tags: javascript

I'm doing Codecademy to get a better understanding of JavaScript and it's saying the code I'm writing is wrong. But I don't know where it's going wrong. The debug message coming up is:

"Missing an identifier and instead saw 'else', missing ';' before statement"

This issue comes up a lot as I'm writing can anyone let me know what exactly that debug message means so I don't have to come crawling back to you experts? Haha. Anyways, here's the code:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2);
    return("The result is a tie!");
};

else if(choice1 === "rock") {

    if(choice2 === "scissors") {
    return("rock wins");
}
else {
    return("paper wins");
}
}
compare();
```

Comment: You need to remove the simicolon after your *if* criteria: `if (choice1 == choice2) { ...[code goes here]... }`

Comment: `return` is not a function. Don’t parenthesize return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return("The result is a tie!");
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {
        if(choice2 === "scissors") {
            return("rock wins");
        }
        else {
            return("paper wins");
        }
    }
}

compare();
```

I can only guess what this function is supposed to look like

Answer (score -1):

Easy to see if you properly indent your code:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2);
    return("The result is a tie!");
}; // this ends the function, not the if!

else if(choice1 === "rock") {
    if(choice2 === "scissors") {
        return("rock wins");
    }
    else {
        return("paper wins");
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your else if out of nowhere

Comment: @cale_b Yeah, obviously, but I don't like to give a ready-to-use answer to beginners, as they learn nothing from them.

Comment: Still, invalid syntax (`if (choice1 === choice2);`)

Comment: @Johan Mind explaining what is wrong with it? Also my answer should not be final code, but rather highlight the problem.

Comment: Still same issue. Message remains the same and also says, SyntaxError Unexpected Token Else.

Comment: @danteMingione I'm expecting you to read my answer and think about it. I did not say: Grab my answer, it will work fine.

Comment: OK, fair enough. What does it mean when it says ""Missing an identifier and instead saw 'else',"

Comment: @danteMingione I have no idea what Code Academy expects to see there, but I can tell you for sure that the `else` without `if` is invalid. The error message `node.js` gives is: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token else`.

Comment: Oh, so I needed to put curly brackets on the first if statement like I did the others?

Comment: @danteMingione Basically: Yes.